# Can't get image_id from Cloudinary in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, image-uploading, cloudinary

I'm using Node.js and Express. I just implement Cloudinary to upload image from user, and store the image id to my MySQL database.

I tried this tutorial from Cloudinary's documentation: http://cloudinary.com/documentation/node_image_upload. Everything works well, except at the final step, I need to get the `image_id`.

```js
  var url = require('url')  
  var url_parts = url.parse(req.body.coverurl, true)
  console.log(url_parts) //DEBUG
  var query = url_parts.query
  console.log(query) //DEBUG

  var preloaded_file = new cloudinary.PreloadedFile(query.image_id)
  if (preloaded_file.is_valid()) {
    var image_id = preloaded_file.identifier()
    console.log("Img ID:" + image_id)
  } else {
    console.log("Invalid upload signature")
  }
```

The `req.body.coverurl` is something like: `image/upload/v1426989769/f08eodnwt5zqfwb2bgpd.png#f63f1fe77c7f536447e079f3dd10829b5a15d862`
The `url_parts` is:

```json
{ protocol: null,
  slashes: null,
  auth: null,
  host: null,
  port: null,
  hostname: null,
  hash: '#f63f1fe77c7f536447e079f3dd10829b5a15d862',
  search: '',
  query: {},
  pathname: 'image/upload/v1426989769/f08eodnwt5zqfwb2bgpd.png',
  path: 'image/upload/v1426989769/f08eodnwt5zqfwb2bgpd.png',
  href: 'image/upload/v1426989769/f08eodnwt5zqfwb2bgpd.png#f63f1fe77c7f536447e079f3dd10829b5a15d862' }
```

And..., variable `query` is empty. `query.image_id` is invalid so can't get the image id, also can't verify the signature.

I don't know why Cloudinary give this invalid callback string. Or how can I solve this problem.

Thank for your help. And forgive me for my bad English :)

**Update**

**my submit_idea.hbs**

```html
<form action="/submit/idea" method="POST">
    {{{imgtag}}} <!-- this will render from: cloudinary.uploader.image_upload_tag('coverurl') -->
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

**in my routes/submit.js**

```js
router.get('/submit/idea', function(req, res, next){
    // just render the submit_idea.hbs with some Cloudinary variable
})

router.post('/submit/idea', function(req, res, next){
  var url = require('url')  
  var url_parts = url.parse(req.body.coverurl, true)
  var query = url_parts.query

  var preloaded_file = new cloudinary.PreloadedFile(query.image_id)
  if (preloaded_file.is_valid()) {
    var image_id = preloaded_file.identifier()
    console.log("Img ID:" + image_id)
  } else {
    console.log("Invalid upload signature")
  }

  // add image_id to mysql
})
```

Comment: why are you using req.body.coverurl instead of req.url?

Comment: I have updated the question. I think req.url is just get something like `/submit/idea`; not the identifier of the uploaded image.

Comment: I guess what you are looking for is public_id. this in your example f08eodnwt5zqfwb2bgpd. I guess you can extract it from path in url_parts and then try to verify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the docs in cloudinary site is wrong or outdated. Try verifying your upload as below. It should work.

```
router.post('/submit/idea', function(req, res, next){
  /*REMOVE THESE PARTS. I guess these are not needed any more. 
    var url = require('url')  
    var url_parts = url.parse(req.body.coverurl, true)
    var query = url_parts.query
   */
  //Directy pass coverurl to PreloadedFile method. 
  var preloaded_file = new cloudinary.PreloadedFile(req.body.coverurl)
  if (preloaded_file.is_valid()) {
    var image_id = preloaded_file.identifier()
    console.log("Img ID:" + image_id);
    // add image_id to mysql
  } else {
    console.log("Invalid upload signature")
  }
})
```

Comment: Oh yeah! You are right. The documentation is outdated. Using your idea, I read the [source code](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_npm/blob/master/lib/preloaded_file.js). So I find out just need to use PreloadedFile method and we can get the `public_id`. So cool. Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: Great it worked for you. Also I think you should add image_id to mysql inside if(preloaded_file.is_valid())){ ....here....}

Answer (score 0):

[Yalamber](https://stackoverflow.com/users/266598/yalamber) got it right. Our documentation is out of date!

Because the form uses `POST` and not `GET`, the image_id field is provided in the body of the request rather than the URL query parameters.

You can see the correct behaviour in our sample project [photo_album](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_npm/tree/master/samples/photo_album), specifically in [`create_direct()`](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_npm/blob/master/samples/photo_album/controllers/photos_controller.js#L115) (abridged below):

```js
function create_direct(req,res){
  var photo = new Photo(req.body);
  var image = new cloudinary.PreloadedFile(req.body.image_id);
  if (image.is_valid()){
    photo.image = image.toJSON();
  }
  photo.save().then(function(photo){
    console.log('** photo saved');
  }).catch(function(err){
    console.dir(err);
  }).finally(function(){
    res.render('photos/create_direct',{photo:photo,upload:photo.image});
  });
}
```

Thanks for noticing! We will update our documentation very soon.

-- Cloudinary